# Popmodal Function Passing Multiple IDs

Tags: jquery, function, modal-dialog

The following code works great. But it only calls modal1 to show when calling the popModal().
How do I change the code below where id == 'modal1' can be 'modal2', 'modal3' or 'modal4'. If I change the id value it works but I don't want it to be static - it could be any id value. Thoughts?
Thanks for your assistance in advance.

```
var id= getUrlParameter('id');

if (id == 'modal1') {
     popModal();
}

function popModal()
{
    $('#modal1').modal('show');
}


function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{

    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);    

    // var to open modal: url http://example.com?id=modal1



    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the js that I call to see the popup:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ var id= getUrlParameter('id'); 
if (id == 'modal1') { popModal(); } })
```

I tried the following but it popups the same modal (modal1):

`if (id == 'modal1' || id == 'modal2') {
     popModal();}
function popModal()
{    $('#modal1' || '#modal2').modal('show');
}`

And also added the following:

`$(document).ready(function()
{ var id= getUrlParameter('id'); 
if (id == 'modal1' || id == 'modal2'){ popModal(); } })`

Can't seem to get it to work - any help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried this but it pops both windows at the same time.

`function popModal()
{    $('#modal1, #modal2').modal('show');}`

Comment: I also tried:
`function popModal()
{
  $('id').modal('show');
}` I thought for sure this would work but I'm obviously missing something - why isn't pulling the value of the id to popup?

Comment: Last - I also tried the following but for some odd reasons it picks up always the first modal by default...

`function popModal()
{
    $('#modal1' || '#modal2').modal('show');
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//### 1
if (id == 'modal1' || id == 'modal2' || id == 'modal3') {
     popModal(id);
}

//### 2
function popModal(id)
{
    $('#'+id).modal('show'); //### 3
}
```

[TEST](http://jsfiddle.net/kge5rqv3/9/)

1. first checks whether the id is appropriate
2. then call the function to show modal window with appropriate id
3. to display the appropriate modal, id string must begin with #

Comment: Please explain your code also. You will get more votes and the user will understand the problem and solution better.

Comment: Perfect. Works very good and the explanation was easy to understand.